# How do I install Supervisor on CentOS?

Tags: centos, package-management

I have zero-knowledge of Linux. I always found the interface where I get to click things with a mouse curser to be easier for me than black-windows with a lot of text-lines (at least that's my vision of "linux" I guess).

I am starting a website/software of sort and I was requested by my programmers to carry out several things on the server (I purchased a dedicated server with "CentOS" on it, I guess that's Linux):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install supervisor
> ```
>
> Within `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` create a
>   `laravel-worker.conf` file.
>
> ```
> chmod +x laravel-worker.conf.
> ```
>
> Add this
>   content to file `laravel-worker.conf`: (TEXT HERE)

I managed to connect to that black window ("SSH" I understand it's called) using Putty, but then things go wrong - the command "apt-get" doesn't exist, and I found someplace else on google that I can install using "easy_install supervisor" which seemed to be working, only I used that "cd /etc" command to see the filed in the etc folder and there is no "supervisor" folder...

How do I install it?

Also, once I installed it, how do I create a file or how do I fill that file with text if I don't have a screen in front of me or a mouse curser to choose a line and so on?...

I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no need to guess [what CentOS is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), but "CentOS is Linux" doesn't mean "Linux is CentOS": there are different distributions, each with their own way of doing things. I can't personally vouch for these instructions, but they seem fairly up-to-date and comprehensive: [Installing Supervisor and Superlance on CentOS](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/455-Installing-Supervisor-and-Superlance-on-CentOS)

Comment: Congratulations on becoming a CentOS system admin. There's lots of documentation available to bring you up to speed. Read https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/pt-pkg-management.html to learn about software installation, in particular the `yum` command.

Comment: Tell your "programmers" that you are using a CentOS system and, therefore, `apt-get` is the wrong command. Ask them to tell you what you need to do. Do you just need to install supervisord?

Answer (score 2):

Different distributions use different package managers; that's one of their primary distinguishing characteristics. `apt-get` is a command line interface for [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) which is used by Debian, ubuntu, Mint, elementary and others. RHEL, CentOS and Fedora use [Yum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified).

```
sudo yum install supervisor
```

If you're going to administer a CentOS machine, you should read the [documentation](https://wiki.centos.org/Documentation). CentOS is very close to RHEL, so Red Hat documentation will often (but not always) apply too.

If you want a distribution that can be administered without using the command line, CentOS isn't the best choice; it's primarily intended for professionals. If you want to do professional system administration, you do need to be reasonably comfortable with a command line. If you want to administer remote machines, you do need to be reasonably comfortable with a command line.